# Create a trigger for a discount on a plane ticket

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger where I need to check how many plane tickets the passenger has bought in one specific year. If the value of all the acquired tickers that year isgreater than $1000, or if the amount passes $1000, a 10% discount on the next plane ticket should be registered.

I made something but it's only the beginning, I thought also about using an `IF` to check if the tickets bought in that year were greater than 1000$ but I don't know if that's gonna work out.

I Leave the beginning of the trigger and the tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Ticket.discount
ON dbo.Ticket
AFTER 
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT t.number , t.totalFare , t.docReference
FROM dbo.Ticket
INNER JOIN dbo.Passenger p ON t.docReference = p.docReference


CREATE TABLE Ticket(
    number int NOT NULL,
    issueDate date NOT NULL,
    issueTime time(0) NOT NULL,
    totalFare decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL,
    currency nchar(3) NOT NULL,
    discount decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL,
    docReference nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    documentType nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    nationality nchar(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Ticket_number PRIMARY KEY (number),
CONSTRAINT FK_Ticket_Passenger_docReference_documentType_nationality FOREIGN KEY (docReference, documentType, nationality) REFERENCES Passenger
)



   CREATE TABLE Passenger(
    docReference nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    documentType nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    nationality nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    yearCreated date NOT NULL,
    title nchar(3) NULL,
    [name] nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
    middleNames nvarchar(100) NULL,
    surname nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
    passportReference nchar(10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Passenger_docReference_typeOfDocument_nationality PRIMARY KEY (docReference, documentType, nationality),
CONSTRAINT FK_Passenger_Country_nationality FOREIGN KEY (nationality) REFERENCES Country (ISOalpha2Id),
CONSTRAINT FK_Passenger_DocumentType_documentType FOREIGN KEY (documentType) REFERENCES DocumentType([type])
)
```

Comment: Some of this text looks like it has come through a translator, and I'm struggling to follow what it's trying to say. I *think* I've managed to maintain the intent but please do check it over.

Comment: What is your `TRIGGER` trying to do here? It just `SELECT`s some data, however, returning data with a `SELECT` in a trigger is deprecated, and should be avoided.

Comment: The Function of the trigger is to add a discount on a new plane ticket. If the tickets in one specific year for example 2019 overdue the amount of 1000 $ the trigger should insert the 10% discount on that new plane ticket.

Comment: This seems like something that should be worked out *before* you `INSERT`, not afterwards. When purchasing an item online, for example, I wouldn't place my order for £2,000, pay £2,000 and then the website discount £200 *afterwards* and refund me £200. Instead the system should note that the order is over £1000 and discount 10% from it. If the order is Under £1000 then it should check what I have spent so far this year and discount appropriately in "basket". Then the *discounted* price should be `INSERT`ed.

Comment: That's not the clear objective, let's say I buy 10 tickets in 2021 If the total of that 10 tickets is superior to 1000$ then on the next ticket I should get a 10% discount

Comment: Yes, so when you buy your **11th** ticket, you check if the client should get a discount or not, and then apply it **before** you `INSERT` it. A `TRIGGER` is the wrong solution here, because then the order has already been placed and the client has been given the *wrong* price.